# How do I handle the onclick to expand a single element from flatlist item

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Code is pretty straightforward, I'm using `react-native-collapsible`, I need to handle the onclick to expand the single item I clicked instead of every element of the flatlist, please do not suggest an accordion component for this, I don't think I need a new component to make this.

This is a flatlist contained inside a flatlist, and the collapsible is part of that.

```js
<FlatList
  extraData={this.state}
  data={this.state.displayDay} //{DataManager.FavoriteList[moment(this.state.selectedDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')]}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: hp("2%") }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            alignSelf: "center",
            width: wp("95.7%"),
            height: 75, //hp('10%'),
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
          }}
          onPress={() => this.toggleExpanded()}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <Text
                numberOfLines={2}
                ellipsizeMode="tail"
                style={{
                  marginLeft: wp("5%"),
                  width: wp("55%"), //wp('38.2%'), //151
                  //height: hp('2%'), //19
                  fontSize: rfv(16),
                  fontWeight: "500",
                  fontStyle: "normal",
                  textAlign: "left",
                  color: "#707070",
                }}
              >
                {item.Title}
              </Text>
              <Text
                style={{
                  marginLeft: wp("5%"),
                  fontSize: rfv(14),
                  fontWeight: "normal",
                  fontStyle: "normal",
                  textAlign: "left",
                  color: "#c4c4c4",
                }}
              >{`ID ${item.Id} - ${item.Cliente}`}</Text>
              {!item.IsFavorite ? (
                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: wp("5%"),
                    fontSize: rfv(14),
                    fontWeight: "normal",
                    fontStyle: "italic",
                    textAlign: "left",
                    color: "#c4c4c4",
                  }}
                >
                  No favorito
                </Text>
              ) : null}
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginRight: wp("3.4%") }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: rfv(18),
                    fontWeight: "300",
                    fontStyle: "normal",
                    textAlign: "right",
                    color: "#707070",
                  }}
                >{`${item.HorasTotales}h`}</Text>
                <Image
                  style={{ marginTop: hp("1%"), marginLeft: wp("3.7%") }}
                  source={
                    this.state.isCollapsed
                      ? Images.expandible
                      : Images.collapsible
                  }
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Collapsible
          duration={100}
          style={{
            alignSelf: "center",
            width: wp("95.7%"),
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
          }}
          collapsed={this.state.isCollapsed}
        >
          <FlatList
            extraData={this.state}
            data={item.ListReportHistoryResponse} //{DataManager.FavoriteList[moment(this.state.selectedDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')]}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                <View>
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        marginLeft: wp("5%"),
                        fontSize: rfv(14),
                        fontWeight: "normal",
                        fontStyle: "normal",
                        textAlign: "left",
                        color: "#717171",
                      }}
                    >
                      Etapa
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        marginLeft: wp("42.5%"),
                        fontSize: rfv(14),
                        fontWeight: "normal",
                        fontStyle: "normal",
                        textAlign: "left",
                        color: "#717171",
                      }}
                    >
                      Horas
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                    <ModalDropdown
                      adjustFrame={(style) => {
                        style.top =
                          Platform.OS === "ios"
                            ? style.top
                            : style.top - StatusBar.currentHeight;
                        return style;
                      }}
                      dropdownTextStyle={styles.dropdownTextStyle}
                      dropdownTextHighlightStyle={
                        styles.dropdownTextHighlightStyle
                      }
                      dropdownStyle={styles.dropdownStageStyle}
                      defaultValue={item.Etapa}
                      style={styles.dropStageStyle}
                      textStyle={{
                        padding: 0,
                        margin: 0,
                        fontSize: rfv(16),
                        paddingVertical: hp("1.2%"),
                        fontWeight: "normal",
                        fontStyle: "normal",
                        textAlign: "left",
                        color:
                          item.Etapa /*item.ListReportHistoryResponse[index2].Etapa*/ !=
                          "Selecciona una etapa"
                            ? "#1a1a1a"
                            : "#c4c4c4",
                      }}
                      //onSelect={(index, value) => this.setState({SeleccionClientes: value})}
                      //options={Object.keys(this.state.items)}
                      onSelect={(index, value) =>
                        this.onSelectEtapaChange(index, value)
                      }
                      options={DataManager.ListEtapa}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.InputContainerHours}>
                      <Text style={styles.InputTextHours}>
                        {item.HorasTrabajadas}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={{ marginTop: hp("0.5%"), marginLeft: wp("5.5%") }}
                      onPress={() =>
                        this.onSubstractHourChange(index, item.HorasTrabajadas)
                      }
                    >
                      <Image source={Images.menos_hora} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      style={{ marginTop: hp("0.5%"), marginLeft: wp("2%") }}
                      onPress={() =>
                        this.onAddHourChange(index, item.HorasTrabajadas)
                      }
                    >
                      <Image source={Images.mas_hora} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: rfv(14),
                      marginLeft: wp("5%"),
                      fontWeight: "normal",
                      fontStyle: "normal",
                      textAlign: "left",
                      color: "#717171",
                    }}
                  >
                    Observaciones
                  </Text>
                  <Input
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    maxLength={100}
                    inputContainerStyle={styles.InputContainerComentarioOnBlur}
                    containerStyle={styles.InputComentario}
                    inputStyle={styles.InputTextHoursRInput}
                    placeholderTextColor={"#c4c4c4"}
                    placeholder="(Opcional)"
                    value={item.Title}
                    onChangeText={(value) =>
                      this.onTextObservacionesChange(index, value)
                    }
                  />
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{ alignItems: "flex-end", alignSelf: "flex-end" }}
                    onPress={() => this.onAgregarEtapa(index, "")}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        marginRight: wp("3.4%"),
                        marginBottom: hp("3%"),
                        fontSize: rfv(14),
                        fontWeight: "normal",
                        fontStyle: "normal",
                        textAlign: "left",
                        color: "#1062cc",
                      }}
                    >
                      Agregar etapa
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
        </Collapsible>
      </View>
    );
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making a mistake here. All of your item's collapsed state is base on `this.state.isCollapsed`.

So it means, when you change your `isCollapsed` state, all of your items in flatlist will change with it.

So, my suggestion is put something like your onclick item's id in state, and change the collapsed state of each item base on that id.

Something like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{
  alignSelf: 'center',
  width: wp('95.7%'),
  height: 75,//hp('10%'),
  backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
}} onPress={() => this.setState({clickedItem: item.id})}
```

then your item in flatlist

```
collapsed={this.state.clickedItem !== item.id}
```

Hope that help.

Comment: If your item's current status is expand you just need to set `clickedItem` to null, it will collapsed

Comment: can you elaborate on that one please?

Comment: what's the initial state for clickedItem?

Comment: You can set it to null at the initial.. then when on click, you can do this `this.setstate({clickedItem: (this.state.clickedItem === item.id) ? null : item.id})`

Comment: mmm is not working, all my elements are getting expanded :/

Comment: just one last thing, i got this image of an arrow that get's displayed pointing up when is collapsed, or pointing down when is expanded, do you know how to set this in order to move ONLY the element that is expanded or collapsed?

Comment: You can do like this.
`<Image style={{marginTop: hp('1%'), marginLeft: wp('3.7%')}} source={this.state.clickedItem === item.id ? Images.expandible : Images.collapsible}/>`

Answer (score 1):

But can't you render 2 different views based on the state?? If collapsible true then render viewA else viewB, where viewA is your collapsed view while viewB is expanded one. That would be simple and pretty straight without messing code and using third party

Comment: (How) Can this approach be taken for just a single item of the Flatlist ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a little bit?